# Can events fired from an iframe be handled by elements in its parent?

Tags: javascript, firefox, prototypejs

Suppose I have a page located at `www.example.com/foo`, and it contains an `<iframe>` with `src="http://www.example.com/bar"`. I want to be able to fire an event from `/bar` and have it be heard by `/foo`. Using the Prototype library, I've tried doing the following without success:

> Element.fire(parent, 'ns:frob');

When I do this, in Firefox 3.5, I get the following error:

> Node cannot be used in a document other than the one in which it was created"  code: "4
>   Line 0

Not sure if that's related to my problem. Is there some security mechanism that's preventing scripts in `/bar` from kicking off events in `/foo`?

Comment: Are foo and bar in the same domain?

Comment: @Annie the scheme and domain portions of the URL's are the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't tested this cross-browser yet, but it works in FF.

In the iFrame you can fire on the element parent.document:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  parent.document.fire('custom:event');
});
```

and in the parent frame you can catch it with:

```
document.observe('custom:event', function(event) { alert('gotcha'); });
```

Comment: Ah. I think the key here is that you used parent.document. The difference is that parent is a Window object vs. parent.document is an Element. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Events can be handled by a function defined the parent window if the `iframe` is a page from the *same* domain (see MDC's article on [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)); however, events will not bubble up from the `iframe` to the parent page (at least not in my tests).

Comment: Thanks alot, Justin. Can you (or someone else) provide a link about events not bubbling up from an iframe?

Comment: From [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling): "propagation will continue up to and including the Document." It is important to understand that an iframe has an own document element. Again, citing [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#idx-document): "the embedded document remains independent of the main document"

Comment: Specifications are rarely the same as implementations :(

Comment: This is unfortunate, but I understand the reason. It just means  whomever is in control of the other domain should provide hooks to pass events through (assuming you're using a 3rd party library like me).

Answer (score 2):

rather then catch an event on the main page, you can catch the event at the iframe, and call a function on the main page.

```
<-- main page -->
function catchIt()
{
 // code here
}


<-- iframe page -->

function doIt()
{
 top.catchIt(); 
}

<a onclick="doIt();">test</a>
```

i think it would work but didnt test it

Comment: Don't you mean parent.catchIt, not top.catchIt?

Comment: when you have frames inside other frames, top means the parent os all frames.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected, to do what you need:

index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on('eventhandler', function() {               
        alert('event was fired');
    });
}); 
</script>
```

iframe.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    parent.$(parent.document).trigger('eventhandler');  
});
</script>
```