# How to change the Iframe height from its content (both from same domain)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to dynamically change the height of the iframe element from content of this iframe, here is my js:

```
function iframeLoaded()
{
    var iframeID = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframeContainer');
    if(iframeID) {
        console.log('if');
        iframeID.height = "";
        iframeID.height = iframeID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

I run this function whenever the content height change. And I've got Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

What can be wrong with this.
**Parent and children site are in same doamin!**

Parent http://example.com iframe part of html code:

```
<iframe id="iframeContainer" class="wrapper" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="700" frameborder="1" src="http://example.com/ext/index.php" name="iframe">...</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to do it the other way around. You can trigger the parent from the iframe. Something like this (if you use jQuery that is):

```
parent.$('body').trigger( 'eventName' );
```

Have a look at this earlier thread also:
[Can events fired from an iframe be handled by elements in its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046737/can-events-fired-from-an-iframe-be-handled-by-elements-in-its-parent)

By the way, you wrote "I run this function whenever the content height change". how do you get that change now?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake
It wasn't same domain (one have www the other doesnt) =/