# How to make an iframe auto-resize along with the dynamic changes on its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this js code I searched on **auto-resizing iframe height with its content**. It does what the user who posted this says it does. However, I now have this problem with dynamic content within the iframe.

The js code I have works only with the regular content of the page but not when there are dynamic changes going on within. For example, displaying texts through ajax call.

I've tried searching for other solutions to this but others did not work as well as what this code can do.

I'm hoping that there's someone who could help me update the code to meet what I currently need. I'm not very familiar with jquery/javascript to do this on my own. Thank you in advance! :)

**This is the JS code:**

```
function setIframeHeight(iframeId) {

    var ifDoc, ifRef = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    try {
        ifDoc = ifRef.contentWindow.document.documentElement;
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ifDoc = ifRef.contentDocument.documentElement;
        } catch (ee) {}
    }

    if (ifDoc) {
        ifRef.height = 1;
        ifRef.height = ifDoc.scrollHeight;

        /* For width resize, enable below.  */

        //ifRef.width = 1;
        //ifRef.width = ifDoc.scrollWidth; 
    }
}
```

I found this other code which enables iframe adapting to its dynamic content but I do not know how to make the code above and this work together. Please help me.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow;
iframe.$(".toggle_div").bind("change", function () {
$("#ifr").css({
    height: iframe.$("body").outerHeight()
    });
});
```

To summarize, I need a code that autoresizes iframe with its content and will autoresize again if there are changes on the size of the content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your page doesn't have any trigger indicating to resize when the iframe body resizes.

There also (as far as I know) isn't anything built into javascript that lets you watch for changes in an elements height.

You have two options.

If you are the owner of the iframe content, you can put a script in that page which can call to it's parent window telling the parent to run your resize script, or you can run a function which checks for changes say every second or so.

For the first method, you can follow the answer from here [Can events fired from an iframe be handled by elements in its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046737/can-events-fired-from-an-iframe-be-handled-by-elements-in-its-parent)

Otherwise just do a

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#ifr").css({
    height: iframe.$("body").outerHeight()
    });
  },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function adjustMyFrameHeight()
            {
                var frame = getElement("myFrame");
                var frameDoc = getIFrameDocument("myFrame");
                frame.height = frameDoc.body.offsetHeight;
            }
```

call this method on your iframe onload event and replace mtFrame to your iframe Id

Comment: It didn't work and I received a warning "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\ECE\index.php:192) in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\ECE\index.php on line 195" :(

Comment: i used thiscode alot,check your ifram name and getelement name