# How to pass variable from vanilla JS to Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm trying to get an object title from a vanilla javascript and retrieve it on my angular 2 component. At the moment I'm saving the variable to `localStorage` however I don't think that's a good way of doing it.

To save the variable to `localStorage` is being set when button is clicked, button is in iframe.

Can someone point me to the right direction how to achieve this?

Edit re the answer below: Rest of the red bit are "Cannot find name"
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can emit an event and listen to it in Angular

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('js-value', { bubbles: true, detail: 'someValue' });
```

and then listen in Angular

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('window:js-value', ['$event.detail'])
  onJsValue(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

This way you also won't have issues with change detection because Angular runs change detection by itself when an event handler is called.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you explain the top bit more? I'm guessing that's gonna be in js and "someValue" is the value I'm trying to get? The @hostListener I get declaration expected err and onJsValue name not found.

Comment: Yes, `window.dispatchEvent()` is JS. The other part needs to be inside a component. Please post the exact error message if that is not enough information.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the window.dispatchEvent(), I've posted the error in my original post. I put it in my constructor, not sure if that's the right place to put it basically just following this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-var.html and thought it'd be similar.

Comment: `onJsValue()` is a property in the component class and `@HostListener()` is a decorator. Don't put it inside the constructor.

Comment: So I remove the @HostListener() from the constructor and just put it inside my component class, but its not show me the console.log. Oh btw the variable I'm trying to get is being set when you click a button.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing the same now. I put the window.dispatchEvent.. in my onclick function, however the @HostLisner is not showing me the console.log(val).

Comment: Did you use the same name (where I use `js-value`) in `new CustomEvent()` **and** `@HostListener()`?

Comment: `window.dispatchEvent` is outside my Angular where I thought it would be because the variable that I'm trying to get is from a vanilla js.

Comment: I see. Just wanted to be sure. Script tags from Angular templates are purged. Can you create a Plunker? Start with https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: Looks its working, doesn't work if the the button is in iframe.

Comment: Ok, didn't know iframes are involved but also didn't know about events from iframes. Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046737/can-events-fired-from-an-iframe-be-handled-by-elements-in-its-parent

Comment: Yeah thought it would, here's the example I meant to post yesterday. I've added the iframe as well to show it http://plnkr.co/edit/4urt9Y9nPBeQ0it9oMiv?p=preview