# jQuery UI datepicker change event not caught by KnockoutJS when datePicker handler is in iframe

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, datepicker

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iFramedatePicker = 
{

init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) 
{

    window.parent.customer.datePickers.initDatePicker(element);

    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        var ctrlValue;
        if (typeof (observable()) == "string")
            ctrlValue = $(element).val();
        else
            ctrlValue = window.parent.customer.datePickers.getDate(element);
        observable(ctrlValue);

    });

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        window.parent.customer.datePickers.destroyDatePicker(element);
    });
},

update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var modelValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if ((modelValue) && (modelValue != '')) {
        var modelValue_Date = new Date(modelValue);
        var controlValue = window.parent.customer.datePickers.getDate(element);
        if (controlValue === null || controlValue.getTime() !== modelValue_Date.getTime())
            window.parent.customer.datePickers.setDate(element, modelValue_Date);

    }

}
};
```

I am using the above code but my datepicker handler is in an iframe.
Problem is that the `ko.utils.registerEventHandler` never fires after changing the date on datepicker.

Comment: Hi @Madhurima. Did that answer help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to fire and catch events when you have a child iframe, then try doing `parent.document` instead of `window.parent`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565981/4887159) answer.

Also, if you're using `parent.document` in the `registerHandler` then the registeration of the event should probably happen in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding event delegation in `update`  and instead of `init` ?
Also use JQUERY functions directly into handler.

```
$(element).initDatePicker();
```